# Testing/mocking a service inside functional container in React/Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am stuck in a weird scenario. I wrote a functional component a few days back. It had state hooks in it and also context hooks. I am calling an API in a function based on a click. Here's the function

```
const gameService = new Game();

const Toolbar = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [addVisible, setAddVisible] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const errorContext = useContext(ErrorContext);
  const appContext = useContext(AppContext);

  const addGame = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const updatedGames = await gameService.add({
        name
      });
      appContext.setGames(updatedGames);
      setLoading(false);
      setName('');
      setAddVisible(false);
      errorContext.setError(undefined);
    } catch (e) {
      errorContext.setError(e);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <StyledToolbar>
      Games
      <IconButton
        style={{ float: "right" }}
        onClick={() => setAddVisible(true)}
      >
        <Plus size={12} />
      </IconButton>
      <br />
      {addVisible && (
        <div className="form">
          <form onSubmit={() => addGame()}>
            <label htmlFor="name">Board Name</label>
            <input
              disabled={loading}
              id="name"
              name="name"
              placeholder="My Board 1"
              value={name}
              onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
              <IconButton type="submit" disabled={loading}>
                <ArrowRight size={15} />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton
                disabled={loading}
                onClick={() => {
                  setAddVisible(false);
                  setName("");
                }}
              >
                <X size={15} />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      )}
    </StyledToolbar>
  );
};
```

This is game Service which is handling the API calls

```
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: API_URL,
      timeout: TIMEOUT
    });
  }

  getAll() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const game = await this.instance.get('/games');
        resolve(game.data);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e.message);
      }
    });
  }

  getById(id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const game = await this.instance.get(`/games/${id}`);
        resolve(game.data);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e.message);
      }
    });
  }

  update(id, body) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const game = await this.instance.put(`/games/${id}`, body);
        resolve(game.data);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e.message);
      }
    });
  }

  add(body) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const game = await this.instance.post('/games', body);
        resolve(game.data);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e.message);
      }
    });
  }

  delete(id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const game = await this.instance.delete(`/games/${id}`);
        resolve(game.data);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e.message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and this is so far test I've written and I am not able to figure out how I can test "Add" method of this class. I am trying to simulate the click and trying to mock/spy on add method.

```
describe("Toolbar Add functionality", () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Toolbar />);
    wrapper.find("IconButton").simulate("click");
  });

  it("Should make an API call when clicked add button", () => {
    jest.mock("../services/game");
    const gameService = new Game();
    console.log(gameService);
    const getSpy = jest.spyOn(gameService, "add");

    const inputField = wrapper.find("form").find("input");
    inputField.simulate("change", { target: { value: "name" } });
    wrapper
      .find("form")
      .find("IconButton[type='submit']")
      .simulate("click");
    expect(getSpy).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

I need help in finding out how I can mock service in a similar scenario because I have the same issue in multiple containers where I am fetching data and updating the calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the promise to resolve setting your test as `async` and using `await` / `act`, this is the method I use but you can find other options by googling `jest asynchronous testing`

```
  import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
  ...
  describe("Toolbar Add functionality", async () => {
    let wrapper;
    let gameService;

    beforeEach(() => {
      // I'm not sure about this arragement for gameService creation though
      jest.mock("../services/game");
      const gameService = new Game();
      wrapper = mount(<Toolbar gameService={gameService} />);
      wrapper.find("IconButton").simulate("click");
    });

    it("Should make an API call when clicked add button", () => {
      console.log(gameService);
      const getSpy = jest.spyOn(gameService, "add");

      const inputField = wrapper.find("form").find("input");
      inputField.simulate("change", { target: { value: "name" } });
      wrapper
        .find("form")
        .find("IconButton[type='submit']")
        .simulate("click");
      await act(async () => await Promise.resolve());
      expect(getSpy).toBeCalled();
    });
  });
```

**UPDATE**

Because your Game service is a class and you are creating new objects to use it, it will be necessary to pass it as a prop so you will be able to spy on the actual object the component is using

```
const gameService = new Game();

const Toolbar = ({gameService}) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  ...
}
```

Comment: @UsmanTahir probably it's because they are two different objects, one is created in your test the other inside your component, you could fix that by passing the game object as prop, I will update answer with details